# Views Slideshow - duplicated pager images (from Taxonomy Term parent) – NO RESULT BEHAVIOR field property

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I need some help with Views Slideshow image gallery.

I'am using Drupal 7 with all latest updates for core, views etc.

I need image slideshow from Taxonomy term image fields with possibility to show parent term images if term (child) images are not available.

I've made a view with Slideshow format and 4 view fields (all are the same image field from taxonomy term). Slideshow have pager turned on, so the same images are used as pager items. I’m using one view filed (term image field) for pager and this field is hidden. Second one view fild is using the same term field for main image.

As I need parent images, I’m also using Taxonomy term: Term ID contextual filter with Taxonomy term ID from Url default value, and Taxonomy term: Parent term as Relationships. So I set another two hidden fields with relationship to parent term and these fields are called from input values in main image field - within NO RESULT BEHAVIOR property. So I have 3 hidden fields an one for main image. One from this 3 hidden is main pager image field, and two others are parent fields for NO RESULT... call.

When I test the view, if main images (targeted term) are not available, parent term images are loaded (this specific parent term has 8 images), this is OK. But the problem is if main images (targeted term) are available (for example 2 images are available), they are duplicated in pager, every image 8 times. I don’t know how to limit this duplication. Is this a Slideshow pager problem, or something else?
I have tried with Querry settings (Distinct) and with all combinations inside Relationship and fields properties, without luck.
Images below shows my view configuration, bad gallery, good gallery and parent gallery (it has ajax pager bellow (8 images)).

I don't have enough reputation for other links to show how gallery should looks like so last 2 png's are provided as they are (just add prefix).

http://www.innundo.net/dse/view.png

http://www.innundo.net/dse/bad.png

dse/good.png, dse/parent.png

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Danijel

Comment: Have you also tried the additional "pure distinct" option in the query settings?

Comment: Yes I did. Distinct and pure distinct are not working.

Comment: Hard to debug from here, but i guess the relationship of the field used for the pager is responsible for the duplicate. Have you tried to remove the relationship just for this field?

Comment: I just tried that. No any improvements :(. I don't now if I can debug this from developer module. I will try to see if I can get some info from that. Thanks.

Comment: It is very simple view and it is very interesting that those things not working as they should. I am in doubt if this approach with NO RESULT BEHAVIOUR property (for images type to be replaced with images) is OK. But as we can use tokens, I do not see reason why not.

Comment: I think so too... sometimes the devil is in the details. I just try to replicate your view here, maybe I see the missing link...

Comment: How did you set up your taxonomy? One vocabulary? Parent item with several images and child item with several images?

Comment: I have several vocabularies, but in this case I'm working only with one. Used parent item is the one of root items and it has 8 children’s. This parent item have 8 images, and it's targeted child have 2 images.

Comment: One interesting thing is that all terms filled with images before I have upgraded my view with this “parent” functionality are shown (proceeded) OK inside view->panel->page. No duplicated images in pager.